# Асинхронное получение данных

Tags: многопоточность, qt, qml

Есть простая вьюшка

```
ListView
{
    id: view
    model: myModel.Items
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 10
    delegate: ...
}
```

И есть класс, который выступает в качестве модели для `ListView`. Заголовочный:

```
class DataCollection : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> Items READ getItems NOTIFY onItemsChanged)

private:
    QList<QObject*> _items;
    QThread *_thread;

public:
    DataCollection();
    QList<QObject*> getItems() const;
    void addItem(QObject*);

public slots:
    void loadData();
    void loadDataAsync();

signals:
    void onLoadFinished();
    void onItemsChanged(QList<QObject*>);
};
```

Реализация:

```
DataCollection::DataCollection()
{
}

void DataCollection::addItem(QObject* item)
{
    _items.append(item);
    // Сообщаяем что коллекция изменилась
    onItemsChanged(_items);
}

void DataCollection::loadData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        QThread::msleep(100); // Для иллюзии долгой работы
        QObject *item = new QObject();
        addItem(item);
    }
    // Сообщаем что загрузка завершена
    onLoadFinished();
}

void DataCollection::loadDataAsync()
{
    _thread = new QThread(); // Создаем новый поток
    // Коннектим сигналы со слотами
    connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(loadData()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished()), _thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished()), _thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    // Переносим в другой поток, иначе выполнение не будет асинхронным
    this->moveToThread(_thread);
    // Запускаем
    _thread->start();
}

QList<QObject*> DataCollection::getItems() const
{
    return _items;
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем. Когда я просто делаю `loadData`, то все прекрасно работает. Но вот когда я вызываю `loadDataAsync`, т.е. запускаю `loadData` в другом потоке, (чтобы данные подтягивались потихоньку, и не вешали все приложение) то если у свойства `Items` указан `NOTIFY`, приложение падает. А а консоль `qml` выводится сообщение вида

> QQmlEngine:​ Illegal attempt to
> connect to
> DataCollection(​0x28fe10)​ that is
> in a different thread than the QML
> engine
> QQmlApplicationEngine(​0x28fe20)​.

Я понимаю - проблема в том что `qml` не может законнектится к модели, т.к. я ее сам перенес в другой поток строчкой `this->moveToThread(_thread);` Подскажите как правильно это нужно делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил я эту проблему вынесением функционала асинхронного получения данных в одтельный класс. Он будет получать данные, по окончании уведомлять модель, а модель уже будет уведомлять представление. Вот код нового класса:

Заголовочный:

```
class DataHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QThread *_thread;

public:
    DataHelper();
    void loadDataAsync();

public slots:
    void loadData();

signals:
    void onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*> items);
};
```

Реализация:

```
void DataHelper::loadData()
{
    QList<QObject*> *result = new QList<QObject*>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        QThread::msleep(100); // Для иллюзии долгой работы
        Phone *item = new Phone();
        item->setCityNumber(QString::number(i));
        result->append((QObject*)item);
    }
    // Сообщаем что загрузка завершена
    onLoadFinished(*result);
}

void DataHelper::loadDataAsync()
{
    _thread = new QThread();
    connect(_thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(loadData()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)), _thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)), _thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    this->moveToThread(_thread);
    _thread->start();
}
```

В класс DataCollection добавляем слот `void onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>);`:

```
void DataCollection::onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*> items)
{
    // Очищаем старые и добавляем новые
    _items.clear();
    _items.append(items);
    // Сооьбщаем представлению об изменении свойства
    onItemsChanged(_items);
}
```

И подправим методы получения данных класса-модели `DataCollection`:

```
void DataCollection::loadData()
{
    _worker = new DataHelper();
    // Подписываемся на сигнал окончания загрузки
     connect(_worker, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)), this, SLOT(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)));
     _worker->loadData();
}

void DataCollection::loadDataAsync()
{
    _worker = new DataHelper();
    // Подписываемся на сигнал окончания загрузки
     connect(_worker, SIGNAL(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)), this, SLOT(onLoadFinished(QList<QObject*>)));
     _worker->loadDataAsync(); // ЗАпускаем асинхронное получение
}
```

Вот в общем-то и все.

Если у кого-нибудь есть решение лучше - буду рад услышать